# How to Modify FlutterFire UI Accent Colour

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme

I've been struggling with attempting to modify the accent colour in FlutterFire UI.

Namely, I'd like to change the blue accent colour [here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64292655/179394275-3a765c05-ced2-45b8-b5ea-22d56e92e42e.png) to a different material colour, such as purple. I've messed around with the app theming to no avail, as none of the ThemeData parameters seem to influence this colour so far. I was wondering if this was possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer to my own question. Turns out the theming is part of the colour scheme property, and I ended up defining the following:

```dart
colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch().copyWith(
    primary: Colors.deepPurpleAccent
)
```

This set them all to deepPurpleAccent!

Comment: Why are you editing elevated button theme?

Comment: apologies, the answer has been edited

Answer (score 0):

accent color is deprecated so now u can user Colorscheme instead like this

```
MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(accentColor: Colors.green),
      ),
      home: NextScreen(),
    );
```

Comment: The accent colour property here doesn't seem to modify the colour of the widgets in FlutterFire UI, rather they seem to use the button themes, and the primary colour

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in theme data

```
theme: ThemeData(
        outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
          style: ButtonStyle(
            padding: MaterialStateProperty.all<EdgeInsets>(
              const EdgeInsets.all(24),
            ),
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple),
            foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
     textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: ButtonStyle(
            foregroundColor:
MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.purple)
  )
 )
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't what I was looking for. This seems to be from the bottom of the page [here](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/flutterfire_ui/doc/auth/theming.md), but that simply changes the button to be filled, and doesn't change the accent colour. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: In background color at the last you see Colors.blue. Change it to Colors.purple or whatever colour you are looking for. Edited my answer

Comment: That seems to change the background colour of [this](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/raw/master/packages/flutterfire_ui/doc/images/ui-auth-theming-button.png) custom button, not the accent colour, since you're defining your own button. Rather, the properties I was looking for were changing the "Register" text colour or "Forgot Password?"

Comment: Those are text button.. editing my answer

Comment: actually it turns out they're all linked to the primary colour in the colour scheme